# Pandas Cumulative Sum over two fields

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

It seems like Cumulative Sums are both a common question but also one that's hard to get your head around even after reading other posts.

Here is my situation:
I have this data:

```
User  | Timestamp   | Period  | Count
User1 | 2006-08-13  | Morning | 1
User1 | 2006-08-14  | Evening | 1
User1 | 2006-08-17  | Morning | 1
User1 | 2006-09-15  | Evening | 1
User2 | 2006-09-16  | Morning | 1
User2 | 2006-09-17  | Morning | 1
```

I want the same table but with a cumulative count of each User+Period combination. So like this:

```
User  | Timestamp   | Period  | Count | CCount
User1 | 2006-08-13  | Morning | 1     | 1
User1 | 2006-08-14  | Evening | 1     | 1
User1 | 2006-08-17  | Morning | 1     | 2
User1 | 2006-09-15  | Evening | 1     | 2
User2 | 2006-09-16  | Morning | 1     | 1
User2 | 2006-09-17  | Evening | 1     | 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cumcount on groupby objects:

```
df['CCount'] = df.groupby(['User', 'Period']).cumcount() + 1

df
Out: 
    User   Timestamp   Period  Count  CCount
0  User1  2006-08-13  Morning      1       1
1  User1  2006-08-14  Evening      1       1
2  User1  2006-08-17  Morning      1       2
3  User1  2006-09-15  Evening      1       2
4  User2  2006-09-16  Morning      1       1
5  User2  2006-09-17  Morning      1       2
```